# How do I Register Autofac Module with Configuration

Tags: c#, .net-core, dependency-injection, autofac

I have a console application with a reference to a class library which in itself has a reference to a class library (waterfall). The problem is I want to register my `IConfiguration` by passing it via the Autofac modules and then having them accessible in the lowest library and I am not sure how to achieve this. (The point of my design is to have a standalone NuGet package which can be referenced by console app or website)

The point is I want to register the main `.dll` (`Notification.Send`) in my new website and not have to worry about registering the lower lever `.dll` (`Notification.Queue`) yet still have access to the websites `appsettings.json`. Here is my example

console application

```cs
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            IConfiguration Configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
               .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
               .AddEnvironmentVariables()
               .AddCommandLine(args)
               .Build();

            var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
            //How to pass "Configuration" to SendNotificationModule?
            builder.RegisterModule(new SendNotificationModule());
        }
    }
```

Notifications.Send (Library)

```cs
    public class SendNotificationModule : Module
    {
        protected override void Load(ContainerBuilder builder)
        {
            base.Load(builder);

            //How to pass "Configuration" to QueueModule?
            builder.RegisterModule(new QueueModule());
        }
    }
```

Notifications.Queue (Library)

```cs
    public class QueueModule : Module
    {
        protected override void Load(ContainerBuilder builder)
        {
            base.Load(builder);

            //Here I want to register a custom interface which I can use to retrieve config from
            //and then use for DI in my Notifications.Queue dll

        }
    }
```

I'm not too familiar with Autofac and perhaps barking up the wrong tree but I have searched everywhere but cant figure this out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why don't you pass it through the module constructors?

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var configuration = // ..
        builder.RegisterModule(new SendNotificationModule(configuration));
    }
}
```

Notifications.Send (Library)

```
public class SendNotificationModule : Module
{
    private readonly IConfiguration configuration;

    public SendNotificationModule(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        this.configuration = configuration;
    }

    protected override void Load(ContainerBuilder builder)
    {
        base.Load(builder);
        builder.RegisterModule(new QueueModule(configuration));
    }
}
```

Notifications.Queue (Library)

```
public class QueueModule : Module
{
    private readonly IConfiguration configuration;

    public QueueModule (IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        this.configuration = configuration;
    }

    protected override void Load(ContainerBuilder builder)
    {
        base.Load(builder);

        //Here I want to register a custom interface which I can use to retrieve config from
        //and then use for DI in my Notifications.Queue dll

    }
}
```